Unable to call the function of Child Component in Parent Component onScroll
I am able to close the HeadlessUI Menu component when I call the function through onScroll event within the child component but when I am passing it to the parent component and calling the same function through onScroll method in parent component, it's not working as its meant to be, please can someone spare some time to have a look where is the error. I need to make it work; I am struggling with this since weeks.
Here is the minimal reproduction:
https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/fancy-tree-x3vs7x

/* Parent Component */
import { useRef } from 'react'
import SidebarMenuElement from '@/Layouts/Authenticated/Partials/Sidebar/MenuElement'

export default function Sidebar() {
    const sidebarMenuElementRef = useRef()

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div
                    className="h-full w-[inherit] overflow-y-auto scroll-smooth"
                    style={{ scrollbarGutter: 'stable both-edges' }}
                    onScroll={() => sidebarMenuElementRef.current}
                >
                    <nav>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                {navigation.map((item, i) => (
                                    <li key={item.name}>
                                        <SidebarMenuElement
                                            data={item}
                                            ref={sidebarMenuElementRef}
                                        />
                                    </li>
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

/* Child Component */
import { useRef, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react'
import { Menu, MenuButton, MenuItem, MenuItems } from '@headlessui/react'
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/react'

const SidebarMenuElement = forwardRef(function SidebarMenuElement(props, ref) {
    const { data } = props

    const menuButtonElementRef = useRef(() => {})

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => () => menuButtonElementRef.current())

    return (
        <>
            <Menu>
                {({ close }) => (
                    <>
                        <MenuButton
                            ref={() => (menuButtonElementRef.current = close)}
                        >
                            <span>
                                <data.icon />
                            </span>
                        </MenuButton>
                        <MenuItems onScroll={menuButtonElementRef.current}>
                            <MenuItem>
                                <Link />
                            </MenuItem>
                        </MenuItems>
                    </>
                )}
            </Menu>
        </>
    )
})

export default SidebarMenuElement


You can stop this by stopping the propagation, which prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree and stops any parent handlers from being notified of the event.
onClick={(e) => {
e.stopPropagation();
}}

Hope this helps! If it doesn't, please share the code base using StackBlitz.

Hello mate, thanks for responding, can you please be clear where should I add this, because I am not calling onClick function in my original code, I am just calling onScroll function.

you can add it 0n the onscroll event, it can work for for deffrent event.

Kindly elaborate as the said code as placed is not working! Have added the minimal reproduction as well, please if you can have a look.
